# How to get results only having month and year for the date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

With the below query i want to be able to get data from a specific month/year that i get from a submitted form.
In the form they get to choose two month/year and then user submits form.

Query is working but problem comes in since I do not have the days, and some months have 28/30/31 days.

For example lets say date_one = 2016/01 and date_two=2016/10 i would get error

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

since I have no day in the variables.
I could be solving this problem the wrong way.

How Can I solve this problem with only having month/year for options?

```
SELECT .......
from test_table
WHERE  paid_dt between  <cfqueryparam  cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#date_one#">  and
<cfqueryparam  cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#date_two#"> 
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(year, paid_dt),datename(month,paid_dt),
    datepart(month, paid_dt)
ORDER BY
DATEPART(year, paid_dt) ASC,
datepart(month, paid_dt) ASC
```

I have sql server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use try_convert().. For example

```
Select Try_Convert(Date,'2016/10'+'/01')   -- Notice the addition of /01
```

Returns

```
2016-10-01
```

Invalid conversions will return null.

To get the End of Month

```
Select EOMonth(Try_Convert(Date,'2016/2'+'/01'))
```

Returns

```
2016-02-29
```

Comment: yes i was doing that at first, but not for the second varible date_two not all months have 31/28/30 days

Comment: @anatp_123 modified answer to try_convert()  bogus dates will return null

Comment: Also you can wrap that in YEAR() and MONTH(), so to add to John's answer: SELECT YEAR(Try_Convert(Date, '2016/10' + '/01')), etc.

Comment: @anatp_123 It looks like you are doing date ranges.  for date_two consider date_two = EOMonth(Try_Convert(Date,'2016/10'+'/01'))  This would return 2012-10-31

Comment: i understand your example but lets say i try this for date_two Select Try_Convert(Date,'2016/2'+'/31') , returns NULL, so query wont work

Comment: @anatp_123  2/31 would fail no matter what   try Select EOMonth(Try_Convert(Date,'2016/2'+'/01'))  ... See updated answer

Comment: @anatp_123 what is a value in 'paid_dt'  column.. is it date?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

I dont know about data in paid_dt. (Assumes it has date in it)

```
SELECT .......
from test_table
WHERE (YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,paid_dt)) > YEAR(CONVERT(Date,date_one+'/01')) 
        AND
        MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,paid_dt)) > MONTH(CONVERT(Date,date_one+'/01')))
      AND
        (YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,paid_dt)) < YEAR(CONVERT(Date,date_two+'/01')) 
        AND
        MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,paid_dt)) < MONTH(CONVERT(Date,date_two+'/01')))
GROUP BY YEAR(paid_dt), MONTH(paid_dt)
ORDER BY YEAR(paid_dt) ASC, MONTH(paid_dt) ASC
```